# Azure data factory Dataflow Count distinct

Tags: adfs2.0, azure-data-factory

i have one dataflow with multiple sources and joins and want to create a new column based in the count distinct of column1 from the stream line vs another source, like comparing customerId in the customers_tables vS customerId in the invoice table. In SQL i do it like this:

(select count(DISTINCT customerID) from invoice) AS CustomersWithNoSales,

is there a way to make this comparative using an aggregate transformation in a dataflow?

thanks.

Comment: Data Flow also support we using SQL query to get the data in Source. You could run the query `(select count(DISTINCT customerID) from invoice) AS CustomersWithNoSales`   as Source 1 and `select count(DISTINCT customerID) from customers_tables` Source 2, then using join active to join Source 1 and Source 2. Comparing the customerID with aggregate  active.

Comment: I am comparing to files. Using Datalake as a staging dataset, so what i need is to be able to compare customerID between the customerTable and the invoiceTable.

in the dataflow, they are two sources. One with all the transformatios and the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to add the other source and then join with the other stream. After that i was able to use an aggregate transformation with the function countDistinct between the two fields of each sources.